# Check if anything in one array matches anything in another array

Tags: php, arrays, match

With the following arrays i PHP:

```
$array1 = array(2,9,7);
$array2 = array(6,8,2);
```

How would write the following statement in code:

If any value of `$array1` matches any single value of `$array2`, then `$match = true;`

I imagine this is simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Take a look at [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/function.array-intersect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( count(array_intersect($array1, $array2)) > 0 ) {
    $match = true;
}
```

Comment: had to move the first parenthesis after the 0, then it worked - Thanks!